# Are your questions also closed immediately, either because to simple or too intricate?

Tags: discussion

Increasingly, Stack Overflow has become unusable for me. No matter what I post, someone quickly closes my question. This could be due to the question not being perfectly crafted, the question being too difficult, or a user believing it's a duplicate when it's not. My questions get downvoted within 1 second, suggesting that it was either not a human or they didn't read it. Additionally, there's always someone who misunderstands and closes the question. I just tried to copy and paste the question to ChatGPT, and I received a perfect answer, confirming the question was not utterly ununderstandable. It's disappointing.

As a doctor, data scientist, informatics MSc and medical PhD student, I am not capable of using Stack Overflow anymore. I cannot do it better, I am not perfect, I don't know everything, and no, I cannot design the perfect question. That's why I try to use Stack Overflow, a resource that has been perfect for many, many years.

You can't ask simple questions because they get closed quickly. You also can't ask complicated questions because if someone doesn't understand them, they close them too.

What do you think about that? Is it just me or do others experience the same issue?

(For reference: The question was [How can I restart a socket using a Python application under Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77986192/how-to-restart-a-socket-using-python-app-under-ubuntu) - ChatGPT gives an appropriate answer to that. An example is not needed, as this is a normal Linux behaviour. The error message is also obvious (Socket in use). And no, the question is just as good as I can do; a Google senior developer would have made it better.)

Comment: *I just tried to copy and paste the question to ChatGPT, I received a perfect answer, confirming the question was not utterly inunderstandable.* No, you confirmed that a trashcan was able to make up a string of prediction tokens. ChatGPT isn't designed to find the right answer, it's designed to write. It doesn't understand what it's writing, only that its duty is to write without question.

Comment: I strongly suggest removing any mention of ChatGPT from this question. Regardless of any merits of your question, simply mentioning Gen AI in anything but a negative light, will result in a negative reaction to your meta question.

Comment: A question being understandable or not is only part of a reason for closure. A perfectly written "question" on why the colour green is your favourite colour would still be closed, even though anyone with even basic knowledge of English could understand it; the reason it's closed it because it doesn't fit the guidelines of the site, not because it was "inunderstandable".

Comment: Take note that your question has a closure banner which tells you what to do to get it in shape; especially the linked help page should help you proceed. Critically,  for your case the question should probably include a small setup of the FastAPI program itself (preparing this makes it clear whether it's a general or app-specific problem) as well as how you actually restarted the program (e.g. via systemd, kill, ...).

Comment: Actually that is what I want to discuss. No matter what you write, you get a downvote, this is the perfect example.

Comment: I mean, that's pretty easy to prove false, see any question asked recently that doesn't have a downvote.

Comment: As a new user to Meta you might not be aware, but votes here are different, @SalkinD . They can, in addition to the "normal" reasons you have on [main], also mean that users disagree with the post; for [[meta-tag:discussion]]s, this could mean the pretext of the discussion, the opinion on the matter that the author of the post expresses, or the way the author approaches the subject.

Comment: Let me explain my downvote here:
You made a couple of false assertions. You compare _users_ answering questions to an overrated AI. You don't really leave much room for discussion, as this reads more like a rant. You didn't tag this question properly.

Comment: The question linked here was closed due to "need debug details", I am really baffled when people then claim it was closed for a different reason, like being "simple" or "intricate", when nowhere that is mentioned. Same for downvotes, you do not know why people downvote, and closing has a specific reason that is displayed in the question itself.

Comment: @cerbrus This is exaclty what I meant. I did not say chatGPT is better, I said it confirmed my question is understandable. Also this is what I meant: you downvoted because you don't like chatGPT, a personal opinion. Too many users downvote for some personal reasons, making it difficult to ask something.

Comment: That CrapGPT understood your question is irrelevant, @SalkinD . I *understand* your question, but that doesn't make the question on-topic. SAying a question is understandable, and therefore ok, is like saying a car has 4 wheels and therefore is fit to drive on public roads, even though it has no breaks, lights, or other basic requirements.

Comment: "*Actually that is what I want to discuss. No matter what you write, you get a downvote*" I checked your last 10 questions and only two of those had a downvote. Let me check all of your questions in total to see if that wasn't just an abnormality

Comment: More false assertions. Your mentioning ChatGPT is far from the _sole_ reason I downvoted this. If that were the ___only___ problem, I wouldn't even have downvoted this.

Comment: _"Too many users downvote for some personal reasons, making it difficult to ask something"_. You should be open to the idea that many of the downvotes are not, in fact, personal. But a result of qualities of the questions themselves. The whole ChatGPT thing is a rather unfortunate distraction.

Comment: @VLAZ true that, I deleted the others. Maybe "all" was a little bit exagerrated.

Comment: It's the existing curated content that makes SO so useful and valuable. That's the beauty of it -- you don't need to ask anything at all to benefit, just read. What it's not, is your personal help desk. We're not here to do your research for you. | Frankly, if a chatbot can give you a satisfactory solution, it's a good sign that what you're asking has been covered countless time on the internet already.

Comment: Step 1: Learn to [ask questions in English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4yWEt0OSpg&t=1m49s). It isn't sufficient to tag a question mark at the end of a statement.

Comment: @DanMašek Exactly. 99 times out of 100 I don't *need* to ask my question on SO, because somebody else already asked it. And if ChatGPT can give the correct answer, that likely means the correct answer was already in its training data.

Comment: Asking questions is not the primary use of stack overflow

Comment: Note: If Chat GPT can answer your question properly it probably shouldn't be asked here. The only time GPT gets things right is when the problem and solution are so widely known that they're found solved in the GPT database the same way often enough that it can "generate" the same solution. If the solution is already widely-known, the question is not going to be seen as very useful, particularly because it likely has already been asked and answered several times already.

Comment: *a Google senior developer would have made it better.* I wouldn't count on that. Slinging slick code and asking slick questions aren't necessarily related skill sets.

Comment: One beef I have with the "ChatGPT is so much better than SO" is that when you solve a problem on SO, you get to collaborate with a huge community of programmers on finding answers. Everyone wins. When you solve a problem with ChatGPT, nobody knows or benefits except maybe OpenAI. In fact, OpenAI leeches off work humans have been doing since programming was invented. It's cool that you like ChatGPT and all, but it's worth thinking about the greater good rather than just "how can I solve _my_ immediate problem as fast as possible?" ChatGPT is basically a fancy autocomplete trained on our work.

Comment: Your most recent question is a how-to question where you ask why your code does not work properly in a specific environment, but you don't provide the code. That is like going to a mechanic and saying "My car doesn't work properly if I put it in the third gear. Can you fix it?" - without bringing the car for the mechanic to look at. If you think that is a good question to ask on Stack Overflow, there is only one truth here. Your idea of what Stack Overflow is has always been faulty, but it took way too long for curation to  give you that signal and now it is going to be very hard to accept it.

Comment: Why *didn't* you edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You would have received the answer you needed if you had.

Comment: "My questions get downvoted within 1 second, suggesting that it was either not a human or they didn't read it." It definitely does not happen that quickly, but determining that a question doesn't meet standards is often very quick, because the problem is very obvious. "You can't ask simple questions because they get closed quickly. You also can't ask complicated questions because if someone doesn't understand them, they close them too." That is not why they are being closed, and anyway **that does not mean you can't ask them**. You can **fix** the question and **get it reopened**.

Answer (score 25):

Your question lacks necessary debugging details.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77986192/how-to-restart-a-socket-using-python-app-under-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment137489618_77986192) by [President James K. Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/president-james-k-polk):

> You don't specify if it's a server socket, you don't indicate if you close the socket, and so forth. That's why questions should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In general, you should enclose socket handling functions in some construct like `try-catch-finally` or `with` to properly close them in case of abnormal events. Also, see this question for re-using address/port combinations for server sockets.

Humans answering questions are not machines. We need these details to help you figure out what the issue is.

Just because ChatGPT can spit out an answer that seems to work for you, doesn't mean your question is of sufficient quality.

ChatGPT doesn't *understand* what you put into it, nor does it "reason" or validate its output.

Comment: Also - ChatGPT can work with incomplete information and is happy to just shoot in the dark. After all, if that wasn't the correct answer, you can just ask again and provide these details. On SO we aren't trying to blindly guess. One *could* write an answer with some assumptions. But we strive for *accurate* answers. Not a back-and-forth trial-and-error. Different use cases of both services.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did not want to say that chatGPT is better, that is exactly why I try to use stackoverflow. It just confirmed the question is theoretically understandable. And no, try-catch-with does not work in this setting.

Comment: @SalkinD your comment about ChatGPT does not show it's _"theoretically understandable"_. It shows that the language model is trained on enough data that it can spit out something that happens to help you. Comparing an (overrated) AI to human comprehension is not helpful. Also, this isn't a comment, it's an answer ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus still, the "overrated AI" provided a correct answer, the "overrated users" did not. But I do not want the "overrated AI" answer, I want answers from people, that have better answers.

Comment: Then write better questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus I cannot. I am not a google senior developer. It is getting too difficult to craft a question...

Comment: You don't need to be a "senior developer" to add some example code/config to your question... Something that can be used to reproduce the issue...

Comment: @SalkinD To write better questions, consider the feedback you get in comments (that is their purpose), ignoring it will make sure that your questions are closed and downvoted.

Comment: After reading baeldung.com/linux/close-socket-time_wait I do not actually think my question is silly or incomplete. This seems to be a normal unix behaviour. I bet many people would have known the answer, if not closed immediately.

Comment: _I want answers from people, that have better answers_ and those people are telling you to write better questions. If you can’t, so be it. You don’t just get given everything because it’s what you want.

Comment: "It is getting too difficult to craft a question." - It actually isn't that difficult.

Comment: @SalkinD What you are asking for help on in the socket question isn't a bad question. It's all in how you are asking it. If people have to guess, the question is weak. The more assumptions they have to make to answer the question the less likely the answer is to be correct. We are trying to build a repository of high quality questions and answers. Stuff that will help as many other programmer as possible. If they cannot draw the connections between the question and a guessed-at answer, the answer is not that useful.

Comment: When I read the socket question, my first thoughts were "Good. That is the correct behaviour. It's annoying behaviour while debugging, but it is correct." Tweaking the code to get better debug behaviour to the detriment of correct release behaviour is a bad thing to do. I'd suck it up and exit the code properly as often as I can.

Comment: And I disagree with Security Hound. Writing a good question is hard, but the reward is usually in not having to ask the question. A good question-asking process is also a good question-answering process. As you cross all the 't's and dot all the 'i's grinding out a question worth asking, the problem search space gets smaller and smaller and eventually the problem has so little space left you're going to see it. You may not know how to fix it, and that's the space in which a Stack Overflow question is valuable.

Comment: @SalkinD [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75845973) of what a well-received question looks like, from my own collection. (Of course I can easily answer this sort of thing myself, and wrote this to close duplicates from beginners; but then it turned out that the problem doesn't get asked about as often as I thought.) Does this give you a better idea of how to write them? I don't think it's *that* hard. This is from less than a year ago, so it meets current standards as well.

Answer (score -15):

While I haven't looked into your question in detail (and probably don't know enough details to answer it), and I agree with your sentiment that asking on SO has observationally become less helpful, and a lot of people seem to be trigger-happy with the downvote/vote-to-close buttons (just look at questions that garner down/VTC votes but only have less than 20 views in 1 week or even older), I think the fact that ChatGPT could give you an exact solution to the problem could indicate that the question itself was too simple or even trivial. This is actually a good thing because the exact same problem as yours, or at least something close to it, has probably been asked and answered before, and it's just a matter of finding it. At the end of the day, that's what we're all using this forum for, finding the solutions to our problems.

While it's possible that your question got viewed by a bunch of people that had no idea what you were asking, and down/close voted just for the sake of it, I would rather give them the benefit of doubt and assume all of them were not trolls.

Maybe if you want to discuss how to improve the solution you got from ChatGPT, asking about it in the new discussions feature of SO might be helpful. I haven't used it myself, but this kind of thing seems to be what it's for. I don't know how actively this feature is being used by people, but it might be worth giving a shot.

Comment: *"I think the fact that ChatGPT could give you an exact solution to the problem could indicate that the question itself was too simple or even trivial"* - this part I kind of agree with, but It is too open for wrong interpretation. I would find the truth more in the kind of code you would write in "ideal" situations; when you're still learning and doing simple tasks, or when you're doing a hobby project. VS the kind of code you are forced to write in applications you do under contract. The latter is never ideal and the realm where Stack Overflow shines. The former is more ChatGPT territory.

Comment: @Gimby i dont make any assumptions about why asker needs help. If you can help, do so. If you cant, move on so that someone else thats interested and knows what they're talking about can have a look.